# converting an array of null terminated const char* strings to a std::vector< std::string >

Tags: c++, string, stl, vector

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ function where I'm given an array of null-terminated strings `const char*` and a count of the number of strings in that array.

I'm looking for a clever way of turning an array of `const char*` in to a `std::vector< std::string >`

```
/// @param count - number of strings in the array
/// @param array - array of null-terminated strings
/// @return - a vector of stl strings
std::vector< std::string > Convert( int count, const char* array[] );
```

Boost is fine, STL is fine.

Comment: That's not an array of `const char*`.  Do you mean that the strings are stored sequentially and separated by NULLs?

Comment: There, I fixed it since the OP wasn't responding and the question doesn't make any sense otherwise.

Comment: Of course it made sense, just a different from one you are suggesting

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. @Noah - Thanks for fixing it.

Comment: @Gene: The OP's code didn't match his question, since he said "I'm looking for a clever way of turning an *array* of `const char*` in to a `std::vector<std::string>`" (emphasis mine). He then used a single `const char*` as the function parameter. The question made far more sense than the code -- ergo the code was edited by Noah to reflect the question. To the extent that the OP meant the code instead, it's incumbent on him to say so -- not on you to downvote all the well-meaning answers to what was probably his question.

Comment: Stuart, so you are saying that array of const char* cannot be passed to a function by pointer to the first element?

Comment: @Gene: A pointer to the first element of an array of const char pointers has type `const char **`, since the first element is a `const char *`. You can certainly encode a sequence of null-terminated strings in a char array (and then go on to solve the question from that assumption, as you did) -- and I wasn't arguing otherwise -- but that is not *an array of* `const char *`, which it seems was what the OP meant (it was a simple typo). Anyway, let's move on.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
vector< string > ret( array, array + count );
```

Comment: It always amazes me the poeple that try and do it the hard-way. +1 for keeping it simple.

Comment: Of course, the great thing about this answer is that it is NOT clever.

Comment: @Noah - You're right - I should have said 'simple' not 'clever'.

Comment: The other great thing about this answer is that it's one line long :)

Comment: meh...  One liners don't impress me unless they're truly the simplest method to perform the required task.

Comment: @Gene Bushuyev: @Noah Roberts: Works for me. See below. Simple, obvious, no code required. All plus points. As they all reduce maintenance costs.

Comment: @Noah: Ok, fair enough actually :) In this case it's both simple and short, though.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>


int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    // Put it into a vector
    std::vector<std::string>    data(argv, argv + argc);

    // Print the vector to std::cout
    std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the signature of your function is inadvertently wrong, do you mean something like this?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> Convert(int count, const char **arr)
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    vec.reserve(count);
    std::copy(arr, arr+count, std::back_inserter(vec));
    return vec;
}

int main()
{
    const char *arr[3] = {"Blah", "Wibble", "Shrug"};
    std::vector<std::string> vec = Convert(3, arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is what I started with and why I decided to ask the question. I knew there was an easier way... My brain was just not bringing it to the surface.

Comment: @PaulH: Yup, it's very easy to forget that `vector` has a constructor designed for exactly this situation -- as I think I've proved in this case :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume in your array strings are separated by 0s.

```
std::vector< std::string > Convert( int count, const char* array )
{
   std::vector< std::string > result;

   for(const char* begin = array; count; --count)
   {
    const char* end = begin;
    for(; *end; ++end);
    result.push_back(std::string(begin, end));
    begin = end + 1;
   }

   return result;
}
```

Comment: This code works for the original question, sort of. That is, originally the questioner's function had this signature and so the assumption that the strings are separated by `\0` is reasonable. In that case, this code works. However, the question was edited.

Comment: Obviously not, since it was the old version I was commenting ON.  But whatever.