# Convert char** (c) of unknown length to vector<string> (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, string, vector, c-strings

How would one go about converting a C char** to a C++ vector? Is there some built-in functionality one can utilize to do this, or is it better to accomplish it through a series of iterative steps?

EDIT: For various reasons, the number of elements in the C array is unknown. It is possible I could pass that as another parameter, but is that absolutely necessary?

Comment: Also see [copying c array of strings into vector of std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6307584/1168156)

Comment: And [C++ copying a string array to a `vector<string>`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5839499/1168156)

Comment: And [converting an array of null terminated const char* strings to a `std::vector<std::string>`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4464208/1168156)

Comment: Wow! Those are very similar. However, they all assume the number of elements is known.

Comment: Of course they assume the size of an array (that you have in form of simple pointer) to be known. How else do you want to find out how many strings are stored in your `char**`?

Comment: I was hoping that there existed some way of finding that out. Since the ubiquitous assumption has been that no such method exists, I suppose there really is no way to determine the number of elements just given a char**...

Comment: @MirroredFate: there is indeed no way. Unless your array terminates with a sentinel value (e.g. a null pointer).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can simply use the constructor of `std::vector` that takes two iterators:

```
const char* arr[] = {"Hello", "Friend", "Monkey", "Face"};
std::vector<std::string> v(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
```

Or if you really have a `const char**`:

```
const char** p = arr;
std::vector<std::string> v(p, p + 4);
```

Which will also work with directly using `arr` instead of `p` due to array-to-pointer conversion.

Answer (score 8):

```
char** c;
vector<string> v(c, c + 10);
```

Will construct elements from element of given range. 10 is number of elements here

Comment: The assumption here, and with all the answers, is that the number of elements is known...

Comment: @MirroredFate, you should always know number of elements in c-style array(or pointer points to consecutive elements). In other case you can't do anything, (except deleting if you know it was new'ed and freening if it was malloc'ed)

Answer (score 1):

This one-liner is useful for capturing command line arguments...

```
int
main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  std::vector<std::string> arguments(argv, argv + argc);
}
```

Comment: Now I would use std::string_view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [constructor of `std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) that takes two iterators, a.k.a. ***the range constructor***:

```
char* strings[] = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"};
std::vector<std::string> v(strings, strings + 4);
```

where `4` is the size of your array. In this concrete example, the calculation of the size of the `strings` array would be also possible by using [`sizeof` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof):

```
int len = sizeof(strings)/sizeof(char*);
std::vector<std::string> v2(strings, strings + len);
```

which wouldn't be possible with pure `char**` though since the size of the array can not be directly retrieved from a pointer in any way (also worth to read something about [array decaying](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/1168156)).