# How to copy array of C strings to C++ std::vector<std::string>?

Tags: c++, stdvector, c-strings

The accepted answers in

1. [Convert char** (c) to vector<string> (c++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709585/convert-char-c-to-vectorstring-c)
2. [copying c array of strings into vector of std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307584/copying-c-array-of-strings-into-vector-of-stdstring)
3. [converting an array of null terminated const char* strings to a std::vector< std::string >](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464208/converting-an-array-of-null-terminated-const-char-strings-to-a-stdvector-std)

populate the vector at the same time as declaring it:

```
vector<string> vec(cArray, cArray + cArrayLength)
```

But what if I need to do it separately because I need to expand the scope of the vector, e.g. in

```
vector<string> vec;
if (some_condition)
    // copy a char** to vec
else
    // copy another char** to vec
do_something(vec);
```

How do I copy the arrays then?

Comment: `vec.assign(cArray, cArray + cArrayLength);`

Comment: `std::copy` and `std::back_inserter` too..... research!!

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector` provides an assignment operator:

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;
if (some_condition)
    // copy a char** to vec
    vec = std::vector<std::string> vec(cArray, cArray + cArrayLength);
else
    // copy another char** to vec
    vec = std::vector<std::string> vec(cArray, anotherCArray + anotherCArrayLength )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the copy constructor as

```
if(cond)
{
    vec = std::vector<std::string>(std::begin(arr1), std::end(arr1));
}
else
{
    vec = std::vector<std::string>(std::begin(arr2), std::end(arr2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of answers have already pointed to creating a temporary object, then assigning the result to your destination. As long as you're using C++11 (or later) where this will be done as a move assignment, that's generally quite acceptable.

Another possibility that will work well with older compilers (and new ones) would be something like:

```
char **src;
size_t len;

if (cond) { 
    src = cArray;
    len = cArrayLen;
}
else {
    src = CAnotherArray;
    len = CAnotherArrayLen;
}

vector<string> vec(src, src+len);
```